# SpringBoot: Inject Map from YAML file vs .properties file

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, properties-file

Actually, I can load/inject a Map from a YAML file defined as follows:

```yaml
# custom-auth.yaml
auth:
  providers:
    keycloak:
      enabled: true
      realmUrl: http://localhost:38087/auth/realms/my-app-realm
      clientId: keycloak-client-id
      clientSecret: keycloak-client-secret
      logoutUrl: keycloak-logout-url
    trustbuilder:
      enabled: false
      clientId: tb-1-client-id
      clientSecret: tb-1-client-secret
      logoutUrl: tb-1-logout-url
```

The configuration class is defined as follows:

```java
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "auth")
@PropertySource(value="classpath:custom-auth.yaml", factory = AuthYamlFactory.class)
public class OIDCConfiguration {
    private Map<String, OIDCProvider> providers;

    @Data
    public static class OIDCProvider {
        private boolean enabled;
        private String realmUrl;
        private String clientId;
        private String clientSecret;
        private String logoutUrl;
    }
}
```

We need a factory class to be able to load the above custom YAML file:

```java
public class AuthYamlFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {
    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource) {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());

        Properties properties = factory.getObject();

        return new PropertiesPropertySource(encodedResource.getResource().getFilename(), properties);
    }
}
```

The test proves it works:

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class OIDCConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    private OIDCConfiguration oidcConfiguration;

    @Test
    public void shouldReadSeparateValues() {
        Map<String, OIDCConfiguration.OIDCProvider> providers = oidcConfiguration.getProviders();
        assertThat(providers).containsOnlyKeys("keycloak", "trustbuilder");

        assertThat(providers.get("keycloak").isEnabled()).isTrue();
        assertThat(providers.get("keycloak").getClientId()).isEqualTo("keycloak-client-id");
        System.out.println(providers.get("keycloak"));
    }
...
}
```

I wonder why I can't achieve the same but using the `application.properties` file defined as follows:

```
auth.providers.keycloak.enabled=true
auth.providers.keycloak.clientSecret=keycloak-client-secret
auth.providers.keycloak.clientId=keycloak-client-id

auth.providers.trustbuilder.enabled=false
auth.providers.trustbuilder.clientSecret=trustbuilder-client-secret
auth.providers.trustbuilder.clientId=trustbuilder-client-id
```

The configuration class will be different because I could not map a String to `OIDCProvider` instance:

```java
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("auth")
public class OIDCPropertiesConfiguration {
    private Map<String, String> providers;
...
}
```

Test class:

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class OIDCConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    private OIDCConfiguration oidcConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    private OIDCPropertiesConfiguration oidcPropertiesConfiguration;
...
@Test
    public void shouldReadSeparateValuesFromPropertiesFile() {
        Map<String, String> providers = oidcPropertiesConfiguration.getProviders();
        assertThat(providers).containsOnlyKeys("keycloak", "trustbuilder");

        assertThat(providers.get("keycloak.enabled")).isEqualTo(true);
        assertThat(providers.get("keycloak.clientId")).isEqualTo("keycloak-client-id");
        System.out.println(providers.get("keycloak"));
    }
}
```

The above test fails because instead of having 2 providers, I have 6 ones in this kind of providers Map:

```
{
keycloak.enabled=true, 
keycloak.clientSecret=keycloak-client-secret, 
keycloak.clientId=keycloak-client-id, 
trustbuilder.enabled=false, 
trustbuilder.clientSecret=trustbuilder-client-secret, 
trustbuilderclientId=trustbuilder-client-id
}
```

Changing the data in the `application.properties` file using indexed values as follows:

```
auth.providers[0].enabled=true
auth.providers[0].clientSecret=keycloak-client-secret
auth.providers[0].clientId=keycloak-client-id

auth.providers[1].enabled=true
auth.providers[1].clientSecret=keycloak-client-secret
auth.providers[1].clientId=keycloak-client-id
```

didn't change the result, there are still 6 entries in the map instead of 2.

Why so?
And how to achieve the same as with a YAML file? Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

1. In your properties file add a single property say "`auth.providers`" and as
   a value put a JSON Object as a string that contains context of your
   map.
2. In your code read that value as a String

   ```
       @Value("${auth.providers}" private String authProvidersStr
   ```
3. Use any Json library to parse your Json object into a map.
   This could easily be done with Json Jackson library or Gson library whatever you prefer. I wrote my own JsonUtils helper utility which is a thin wrapper over `ObjectMapper` class  of Json-Jackson library. With this utility your code would be very simple:

```
try {
    Map<String, Object> authProviders = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(authProvidersStr, Map.class);
catch(IOException ioe) {
  ...
}
```

`JsonUtils` class is available as part of Open Source MgntUtils java library written and maintained by me. Here is [JsonUtils Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html) and the library may be obtained as [maven artifact](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.6.0.6/versions) or from [github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out how to make it work.
Here we go:

1. Define the values in `application.properties` file as follows:

```java
auth.providers.keycloak.name=dev.server.com
auth.providers.keycloak.url=https://dev.server.com
auth.providers.trustbuilder.name=prod.server.com
auth.providers.trustbuilder.url=https://prod.server.com

# you can also use an array-based declaration like this:
auth.providers[keycloak][name]=dev.server.com
...# other properties declared the same way, but I find it less readable and more error-prone.
```

2. Create a configuration class as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("auth")
public class AuthConfig {
// The annotation processor automatically considers inner classes as nested properties.
// Setters/getters are mandatory, otherwise it will raise a "property setter not found" error.

    private Map<String, AuthProvider> providers = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, AuthProvider> getProviders() {
        return providers;
    }

    public void setProviders(Map<String, AuthProvider> providers) {
        this.providers = providers;
    }

    public static class  AuthProvider {
        String name;
        String url;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }
    }
}
```

3. Let's test in a test class:

```java
@SpringBootTest
class AuthConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private AuthConfig authConfig;

    @Test
    public void authProvidersShouldContainRightValues() {
        Map<String, AuthConfig.AuthProvider> providersData = authConfig.getProviders();
        Set<String> providers = providersData.keySet();
        assertThat(providers).containsExactly("keycloak", "trustbuilder");
    }

    @Test
    public void providerShouldHaveAttributes() {
        Map<String, AuthConfig.AuthProvider> providersData = authConfig.getProviders();
        assertEquals(providersData.get("keycloak").getName(), "dev.server.com");
        assertEquals(providersData.get("keycloak").getUrl(), "https://dev.server.com");
    }
}
```

Sure, we can access the configuration values wherever you want in your Spring Boot app. Here is an example of its use in a dummy controller:

```java
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    private final AuthConfig authConfig;

    public HelloController(AuthConfig authConfig) {
        this.authConfig = authConfig;
    }

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++");
        Map<String, AuthConfig.AuthProvider> servers = authConfig.getProviders();
        Set<Map.Entry<String, AuthConfig.AuthProvider>> entries = servers.entrySet();
        for (Map.Entry<String, AuthConfig.AuthProvider> entry : entries) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            System.out.println( entry.getValue());
        }
        return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
    }
}
```

Et voilà. Hope this helps.
Voilà.